# Is there any way to put links in buttons with nextcord?

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

So I tried to make a button with a link to rickroll users on a command. I want that there is only one button, but two appeared. Only one button actually opened the link.
My class code:

```
class Rickroller(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(nextcord.ui.Button(style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.link, url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ', label="Get rickrolled"))
        self.value = None
        @nextcord.ui.button(label='get rickrolled', style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
        async def rickroll(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
            await interaction.response.send_message('got rickrolled', ephemeral=False)
            self.value = True
            self.stop()
```

My command code:

```
@bot.command()
async def rickroll(ctx):
    view = Rickroller()
    await ctx.send('rickroll?', view=view)
    await view.wait()
    if view is None:
        return
    elif view.value is True:
        await ctx.send("nothing")#made that for debugging
    else:
        await ctx.send('Would be too funny to get rickrolled by a bot, huh?')
```

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't see it, thanks

Comment: I speculatively fixed the remaining ones, but I obviously had to guess. Please review the changes, and perhaps inspect how I changed the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you add two buttons, one with the link style using `self.add_item` and one without the link style using the decorator. What you probably wanted to achieve, is that the button opens the link and does something in discord, which is not possible. To fix the two buttons remove the button that you add with the decorator:

```py
class Rickroller(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(nextcord.ui.Button(style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.link, url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ', label="Get rickrolled"))
        self.value = None
```

This would be your fixed code for the view.